# Why this process is not running in background?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

So basically i want to run script that will make around 15k pdf files, and it needs to be done from shell because of php max_timeout...

Server: Ubuntu 10.04.1
PHP   : 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5

So what i currently tried:

```
function run_in_background($Command){
    $ps = shell_exec("nohup php5 $Command > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
    return $ps;
}

$ok = run_in_background('/var/www/custom/web/public/make_pdf.php');

if(!empty($ok))
    var_dump($ok);
else
    exit('Fail');
```

And after that i go to ssh console and do `ps $ps` and in response i get headers only with no info - witch means process is not running...

How can i do this so it works?

Comment: try without `echo $!` or ending with `&`. If you want to run 2 proccess 'inline', use `&&` instead of a simple `&`. example: `nohup php5 $Command > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && echo $! &`

Comment: in this case $ok is empty and script returns me Fail.

Comment: @arma how did you know if the process ended with an error? try placing output in a file.

Comment: @jotapdiez i don't know that all i know it did't return PID of the process. Ok how you output everything in file?

Comment: @arma just do `nohup php5 $Command > command_stout.txt 2> command_stderr.txt && echo $! &` and check both files

Comment: Well it gives me fatal error on require_once, thats because my path is build using global `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: @jotapdiez - Ok i made another init file using absalute paths without global variables. And now process is running and i can see it in my shh console. :D Thanks, for assistance. If you care to post it as answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without `echo $!` or ending with `&`. If you want to run 2 proccess 'inline', use `&&` instead of a simple `&`.

Example: `nohup php5 $Command > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && echo $! &`

To check if the proccess end with error do this:

`nohup php5 $Command > command_stout.txt 2> command_stderr.txt && echo $! &`

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a & after Command :

```
$ps = shell_exec("nohup php5 $Command & > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
```

Comment: still no dice, i get the pid okey but process is empty.